# Create all months list from a date column in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE dates(
alldates date);

INSERT INTO dates  (alldates) VALUES ('1-May-2017');
INSERT INTO dates  (alldates) VALUES ('1-Mar-2018');
```

I want to generate all months beginning between these two dates. I am very new to Oracle SQL. My solution is below, but it is not working properly.

```
WITH t1(test)  AS (
SELECT MIN(alldates) as test  
FROM dates 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(test,1) as test
FROM t1 
WHERE t1.test<= (SELECT MAX(alldates) FROM date)                 
)
SELECT * FROM t1
```

The result I want should look like
Test

```
2017-02-01
2017-03-01
...
2017-12-01
2018-01-01
2018-02-01
2018-03-01
```

[image: ideal output]

Comment: What is *not working properly* with your query?

Comment: You have a typo and have written `date` instead of `dates` in the line `WHERE t1.test<= (SELECT MAX(alldates) FROM date)`. If you fix that then your query works. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2eb5c6d924f85d2b4294459f1705e9e1)

Comment: What version of Oracle do you need to run this on? I know you are testing it on SQLFiddle but that is stuck on Oracle 11g and that version has bugs handling dates in recursive queries. So if you particularly want solutions to run on Oracle 11g then you might need to tag your question with that specific Oracle version (because you need an answer that doesn't recurse over dates) and if you aren't tied to a specific Oracle version then stop using SQLFiddle and move to another website that supports a later version (dbfiddle runs on either Oracle 12 or 18 and Oracle's LiveSQL runs on Oracle 19).

Comment: As a side note, you correctly defined the column ALLDATES as  DATE, but then you try to insert a characters string: INSERT INTO dates  (alldates) VALUES ('1-May-2017');  This forces oracle to do an implied TO_DATE on the supplied character string, which will only work if the controlling level of NLS_DATE_FORMAT is correct.  What you _should_ do is provide your own explcit TO_DATE, with the correct format mask:  INSERT INTO dates  (alldates) VALUES (to_date('1-May-2017','dd-Mon-yyyy'));

Comment: @LiryD . . . Your desired results are not consistent with your data.

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo and wrote `date` instead of `dates` but you also need to make a second change and use `ADD_MONTHS` in the recursive query's `WHERE` clause or you will generate one too many rows.

```sql
WITH t1(test)  AS (
  SELECT MIN(alldates)
  FROM dates 
UNION ALL 
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(test,1)
  FROM t1 
  WHERE ADD_MONTHS(test,1) <= (SELECT MAX(alldates) FROM dates)
)
SELECT * FROM t1
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | TEST      |
> | :-------- |
> | 01-MAY-17 |
> | 01-JUN-17 |
> | 01-JUL-17 |
> | 01-AUG-17 |
> | 01-SEP-17 |
> | 01-OCT-17 |
> | 01-NOV-17 |
> | 01-DEC-17 |
> | 01-JAN-18 |
> | 01-FEB-18 |
> | 01-MAR-18 |
> ```

However, a more efficient query would be to get the minimum and maximum values in the same query and then iterate using these pre-found bounds:

```sql
WITH t1(min_date, max_date)  AS (
  SELECT MIN(alldates),
         MAX(alldates)  
  FROM   dates 
UNION ALL 
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(min_date,1),
         max_date
  FROM   t1 
  WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(min_date,1) <= max_date
)
SELECT min_date AS month
FROM   t1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25e7f1668752932b4b41bd072346d9e5)*

---

## Update

Oracle 11gR2 has bugs handling recursive date queries; this is fixed in later Oracle versions but if you want to use SQL Fiddle and Oracle 11gR2 then you need to iterate over a numeric value and not a date. Something like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cebee/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dates(
alldates date);

INSERT INTO dates  (alldates) VALUES ('1-May-2017');
INSERT INTO dates  (alldates) VALUES ('1-Mar-2018');
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH t1(min_date, month, total_months)  AS (
  SELECT MIN(alldates),
         0,
         MONTHS_BETWEEN(MAX(alldates),MIN(alldates))
  FROM   dates 
UNION ALL 
  SELECT min_date,
         month+1,
         total_months
  FROM   t1 
  WHERE  month+1<=total_months
)
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(min_date,month) AS month
FROM   t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cebee/5/0)**:

```
|                MONTH |
|----------------------|
| 2017-05-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-06-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-07-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-08-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-09-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-10-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-11-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-12-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-02-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-03-01T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: @MTO  Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it. But it gives me this [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cebee/4)

Comment: @LiryD Please use [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) rather than SQLFiddle as SQLFiddle is stuck on Oracle 11gR2 and there are bugs handling recursive queries with dates in that Oracle version that have been fixed in later versions.

Comment: @LiryD Updated with a version that will run on Oracle 11gR2 (and SQL Fiddle).... but still, you should move to a website that supports a more modern version of Oracle such as db<>fiddle or Oracle's [LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com) website.

Comment: thank you. I switched to oracle live. every issue is solved : ) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a recursive CTE.  That syntax would be:

```
WITH CTE(min_date, max_date) as (
      SELECT MIN(alldates) as min_date, MAX(alldates) as max_date
      FROM dates
      UNION ALL
      SELECT add_months(min_date, 1), max_date
      FROM CTE
      WHERE min_date < max_date
     )
SELECT min_date
FROM CTE;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e67be8a9a586002d06b1068dc485f4ec) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to run your query. But it only return one row. Please see this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd018/3

Comment: This will generate a date after the maximum date if the minimum and maximum are not exactly 1 month apart. Also, it won't work on Oracle 11gR2 (which is what SQL Fiddle is using) and is why the OP is getting an error.

Comment: @MT0 . . . First, the OP's desired results are inconsistent with the dates provides, so it is a little unclear what nuances might be intended.  This solves the problem *as described*.  I'm not sure what your issue is with the db<>fiddle, but the code works fine, as linked to in the answer.

Comment: @LiryD . . . Run the code through the link provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just made a typo: `date` instead of `dates`:

```sql
WITH t1(test)  AS (
SELECT MIN(alldates) as test  
FROM dates 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(test,1) as test
FROM t1 
WHERE t1.test<= (SELECT MAX(alldates) FROM dateS)   -- fixed here     
)
SELECT * FROM t1
```